# How to choose LCD screen in notebook that can't be seen from "sideways"?

Tags: display

What is the attribute from which I can know that my monitor can't be seen from "sideways"?

E.g. a man is standing on my left, but he couldn't really see my monitor, because it has low "angle" - only the person sitting in front of the monitor can see it. (for security reasons)

Comment: I think LCD manufacturers see a wide viewing angle as a selling point and wouldn't be keen to admit when their product has a narrow viewing angle.

Comment: How about one of theese? http://www.flickr.com/photos/bekathwia/2414194397/

Comment: @Nifle That poor laptop is probably overheating like mad! It's bad enough putting laptops on a bed or something

Comment: @Nifle - If I see these proliferating around the country I shall know who started it...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

there is nothing that the screen can do for you for this... neither is this a s/w feature. what you need is a privacy screen. you can buy one on ebay. this is what you want... [privacy screen](http://shop.ebay.com/i.html?_from=R40&_trksid=p5197.m570.l1311&_nkw=laptop%20privacy%20screen&_sacat=See-All-Categories) choose the right size for your laptop and you're done.

Comment: The ones from 3M are very effective.

Answer (score 1):

The attribute is called "[viewing angle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viewing_angle)", and there are usually two advertised--horizontal and vertical.  180 degrees is a theoretical maximum (more than that would mean you could see the monitor from behind!)

[About.com](http://compreviews.about.com/od/monitors/a/LCD-Monitor-Buyers-Guide.htm) has some information about this..